# select the most recent in all groups of with the same value in one column

Tags: sql, sqlite

The question isn't very clear, but I'll illustrate what I mean, suppose my table is like such:

```
item_name | date added | val1 | val2
------------------------------------
    1     |   date+1   |  10  | 20
    1     |   date     |  12  | 21
    2     |   date+1   |  5   | 6
    3     |   date+3   |  3   | 1
    3     |   date+2   |  5   | 2
    3     |   date     |  3   | 1
```

And I want to select row 1, 3, 4 as they are the most recent entries for each item

Comment: you'll get more answer action if you take the time to review and accept answers to some of your previous questions

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from tableX t1
where t1.date_added = (select max(t2.date_added) 
                       from tableX t2 
                       where t2.item_name = t1.item_name )
```